# Acumatica: Custom Subtotal with an Non-Stock Item

Tags: reporting, acumatica

Very new to acumatica so don't have the terms down completely, so gentle. My issue is with the syntax for the report designer. I have a client that wants to add in a temporary fix to setup a non-stock item to have a separate item total. I need to pull it out of the row and add it to my text field. I have a check for the Item's description to get the Current Unit Price in that line.

In my groupFooterSection1

`=Round(([ARInvoice.FreightTot]) + (iif([ARTran.TranDesc] = 'my non-stock item', 
CDec([ARTran.CuryUnitPrice]), CDec(0))), 2)`

I was looking to do something like `ARTran[2].TranDesc` but that didn't work for this situation. The issue from my snipper is I'm getting only the first item in the group and not the rest. If I switch around the if statement it will do the last one. However I don't know if the non-stock item will be the last or the first one in the group so that won't do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what a co-work and me figured out, the key was to use the sum.

```
=Format('{0:##0.00}',Round(([ARInvoice.FreightTot]) + Sum(iif([ARTran.TranDesc] = 'my non-stock item', 
CDec([ARTran.CuryUnitPrice]), CDec(0))), 2))
```

I added the format since the round didn't really help. Also in the detailSections I added a visible expression like this to hide the non-stock item.

```
=iif([ARTran.TranDesc] = 'my non-stock item', false, true)
```